# How to make tea essential oil?

Tags: oil, tea

I tried to make my own tea essentials oil by putting small pieces of tea leaves (dehydrated) into my local alcohol (29% vol).

After 1 week, the leaves turned brown, so I removed them out of the bottle. Now the remaining looks dark, strong smell of tea and alcohol.

I wonder if it can be called tea tree essential oil and can be used in beauty products like body wash or even in food?

This is my first time I've tried to make essential oil, so not sure what to do properly as there's no direct instruction on google that show how to make tea oil.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have basically made *tea-flavoured vodka*.

The [tea tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melaleuca_alternifolia) (for essential oil) is unrelated to the [tea plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_sinensis) for the beverage.

Commercially, *tea tree oil* is produced by [steam distillation of the leaves of the tea tree](http://trueblueorganics.co.nz/tea-tree-oil-distillation-process/), specifically [*Melaleuca alternifolia*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melaleuca_alternifolia). Though possible to obtain leaves and perform the distillation, it's probably not practical on a small scale outside of the tea tree production regions. For completeness, [tea tree oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_tree_oil) is toxic; you don't want to eat it.

What you used was conventional tea leaves. The tea beverage is made by steeping (soaking in hot water) leaves of the [tea plant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_sinensis), which have been dried or otherwise prepared (e.g., fermented, roasted, etc.).

Comment: Again, ["tea tree" aka *Melaleuca Alternifolia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melaleuca_alternifolia) has nothing to do with the "tea" you drink. You need "tea tree leaves", not "tea leaves".

Comment: Not to mention... Vodka isn't oil...

Comment: @Catija actually, essential oils are not necessarily an oil either. They are frequently an alcoholic extraction too. So the idea is not that far fetched. But you are right, this specific product has nothing to do with either true oil nor an essential oil.